# Scalatest ExecutionContext

Tags: scala, future, scalatest, scalamock

I would like to know which `ExecutionContext` I should use (and why) on `scalatest % 2.2.6` to run my futures and mock's futures.

```scala
class Foo {
   def foo: Future[String] = Future.sucessful("B")
}

class Bar(foo: Foo) {
   def bar: Future[String] = foo.foo()
}

class MyTest extends WordSpec {

  implicit val ec: ExecutionContext = ??? // ...global? Why global? Why not?

  val myMock = mock[Foo]
  val myBar = new Bar(myMock)

  "..." in {
    (myMock.foo _).expects(*).returning(Future.succesful("A"))
    whenReady(myBar.bar())(_ shouldBe "A")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Just import `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` and this will load the default `ExecutionContext` for the `Future` objects in your tests to work properly.

NOTE: For using Futures on tests is OK the global implicits. For real projects consider to use `ExecutionContext` per case.